# Queries with queues on Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

At some pages there are some not important queries (products views increments , grab facebook likes) that have to run after the full load page just for improving the performance

Until now I made that kind of jobs with ajax on $( document ).ready() .

How can I use Event or Queues features of laravel for achieving that.
Is possible to pass an object (like an eloquent collection) also?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A queue is a server side processing event, that is meant to occur after the user does something. For example, after the user signs up, the system 'queues' an email, so it can return to the user quickly, and send the email later.

You cannot use Laravel 'queues' for page loading. This is a user-side event that needs to happen immediately.

Your use of ajax to load slow elements after the initial page load is good. There are other ways to optimize page loads (such as reducing database queries, html + css + js compression etc).

Comment: Yes I know that queues is server side procedure. I don't want any response from the server,  I just want, for example,  run a Controller  method.

Comment: Then would would queue a job to run in your *original* controller. But your queue would call a class, not a controller, to run some methods later on (like incrementing the counter)